# How to get list of currently working commands in Cygwin?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

Currently working with the linphone-android integration. I have installed some packages during installation of Cygwin.

When I try some of the commands like `ls`, `rm`, `cd`, `wget`, `tar` and etc.. are working fine. But few commands like `shell`, `clean` are not working. It gives error `command not found.`

So, my question is,

```
Is there any way to get list of working commands for Cygwin?
Is there any way to install packages for these commands rather than installing them manually?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the most elegant solution is to use the compgen command:

`compgen -c` lists all the available commands 
`compgen -a` lists all the available aliases

You can also try a more brute approach:

 Get all the paths from cygwin using `echo $PATH` and then for each folder execute `ls -h <folder_name>`

Comment: So basically it returns all the files in "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin" folder. Thanks!

Comment: If you have answer of the other question, it will be really helpful.

Comment: It shows the executable files from that folder and also the ones existent in /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

For installing a package the best way is to install first the equavalent of apt-get: apt-cyg from https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg and put it in /usr/local/bin:
`wget raw.github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg<br>
chmod +x apt-cyg<br>
mv apt-cyg /usr/local/bin<br>`
You can also try running the setup executable used to install cygwin `setup.exe -q -n -N -d -R c:\cygwin -s http://mirror_site_to_use -l c:\local_package_folder` for a local package or `setup.exe -q -P package_name` to let the setup download the package

Comment: It seems that apt-cyg repository is unavailable due to DMCA takedown
Instead you can find Sage from https://github.com/svnpenn/sage which can be used exactly like apt-cyg